# Cron class not found

Tags: magento2.4.4, cronjobs

My cronjob is defined as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Status" method="update" name="vendor_module_status_update">
            <schedule>0 */2 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Class `Vendor\Module\Model\Status` exists and manual test below works fine:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http as Http;
use Magento\Framework\AppInterface as AppInterface;

require '/path/to/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

class TestApp extends Http implements AppInterface
{
    public function launch()
    {
        $update = $this->_objectManager->get(Vendor\Module\Model\Status::class);
        $update->update();

        echo get_class($update);

        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(Bootstrap $bootstrap, Exception $exception): bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/** @var Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

However for some reason execution via cronjob throws:

> Class Vendor\Module\Model\Status does not exist

Any idea what could be a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your class works with Object Manager but does not work when cron running because Vendor_Module module didn't enable yet. Try to check if Vendor_Module is in app/etc/config.php file, if so make sure Vendor_Module does not disable. If you didn't install that module, run setup:upgrade to install and enable the module. Then re-compile code and check the result.
- If you tried the above check but the issue still persists, maybe the `Status` class has an incorrect file path or incorrect namespace.

The file path should be `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Status.php`

The namespace should be `Vendor\Module\Model;`

You can check Magento document for reference: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/crons/custom-cron-tutorial.html

And it is worth adding Vendor\Module\Model\Status to a __construct() of a controller to check if the Class exists and works or not.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue because `$this->_objectManager->get(Vendor\Module\Model\Status::class)` is finding it w/o any issues.

Comment: Also you missed "code" directory in the path

Comment: Maybe case sensitive issue in the file path, or namespace. I've added "code" directory which was missed in the file path.

Comment: Checked it multiple times. Also will not explain why object manager works.

Comment: Do you think maybe Vendor_Module module didn't enable yet? Try to check if Vendor_Module in app/etc/config.php file to make sure Vendor_Module does not disable and if you didn't install that module, run setup:upgrade to install and enable the module. Then re-compile code and check the result

Comment: Unfortunately nothing of those either.

Comment: I think it is worth adding Vendor\Module\Model\Status to a `__construct()` of a controller to check if the Class exists and works or not.

Comment: Works fine via constructor also. Must be something in how I define a cronjob.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I think you should use Xdebug and run cron manually in the command line to debug this issue.

Comment: It turned out that module was not enabled after all. If you update your answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Cool, this issue is not a weird issue at all. I've updated my answer to include your point. Thanks

Comment: Hm. Enabled the module but still the same error. Also can reproduce it while running the cronjob via magerun. Only happens on a remote machine. Locally all is fine.

Comment: Haha. So this was a combination of issues and you nailed them all. Found a place where I types module name in other case. Maybe also ad dit to the answer as the list of possible issues. Thank you mate. Answer is accepted.

Comment: Yeah, just read my comment above, I've already mentioned checking to make sure the module enable. I'll edit my answer to list them all. Glad to help you out.